# Return enum value without calling get function

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible in Java to return the `enum` value without having to call a function to return the value, such as `getFlag()` in my example? If so, how?

```
public enum MessageFlags {
        BIT0((short)1),
        BIT1((short)2),
        BIT2((short)4),
        BIT3((short)8),
        BIT4((short)16),
        BIT5((short)32),
        BIT6((short)64),
        BIT7((short)128),
        BIT8((short)256),
        BIT9((short)512),
        BIT10((short)1024),

        set_freq(BIT0),
        get_freq(BIT1);

        short bitFlag = 0;
        MessageFlags flag;

        MessageFlags(short flag) {
            this.bitFlag = flag;
        }

        MessageFlags(MessageFlags flag) {
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        public short getFlag() {
            return this.flag.bitFlag;
        }

        public short getValue() {
            return this.bitFlag;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No offense, but why does it matter whether it's direct or a method call?

Comment: @Daniel: Because it crowds my if statements.

Comment: I'm confused. Why does a `MessageFlags` have a `MessageFlags` field called `flag`?

Comment: @Kublai: Because I am constructing set_flag(BIT0) which is of type MessageFlags. It is more verbose in my if statement than saying MessageFlags.BIT0.getFlag() and I can say MessageFlags.set_freq.getFlag()

Comment: @Code: It seems like you have a design issue with set_freq. Why is set_freq one of the enumerables?

Comment: @Jeremy: The BIT0 is a generic name for a flag. I basically want to "extend" this by giving an alternate name that essentially means the same thing but in a different context. The MessageFlags enum can be used by other methods but `set_freq` may not be used.. it may be called `set_rx_on` - for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `import static MessageFlags.*;` and say `BITX.getFlag()`.

Here is a complete example:

**A.java**

```
package foo;

import static foo.B.*;

public class A{
    public B value = BAR;
}
```

**B.java**

```
package foo;

public enum B{
    BAR, BAZ, BOO
}
```

Comment: I like this way better than the one I suggested.

Comment: "import MessageFlags cannot be resolved" - that is the error I get.

Comment: @Code, did you use the proper package name? Did you use the word "static"?

Comment: Yes, used static. No package name is defined at the top of my MessageFlags.java file (which contains the enum).

Comment: Then I suggest you put it in a package. You cannot import a class that is not in a package.

Comment: Ok, much better. It is now trimmed to just `set_freq.getFlag()` but is there any way around that. I was missing the `.*` at the end of the import statement. I want to call just `set_freq` without the `getFlag()`.

Comment: Yes, but if I put it as a method in my enum, my other class thinks that it should be a method inside that class and complains that it can't find it. Like, `public short set_freq() { return BIT0.getFlag() }`

Comment: Disregard, `set_freq` had to be declared `static`. This looks great.

Answer (score 3):

Just say `MessageFlags.BITX` and that will return the same value as `getFlag()`

Answer (score 1):

I followed @Jeremy's advice of this:

```
package foo;

import static foo.B.*;
```

and then I created a method called `set_freq` in my `MessageFlags` enum. I made this function `static` and had it return `short`. For example,

```
public static short set_freqflag() {
    return BIT0.getFlag();
}
```

The semantics of `set_freqflag` are a little weird because you are not setting anything but I do not have a better name at the moment. This allows me to just state `set_freqflag()` rather than the longer way I was doing before.

Answer (score 0):

I might be really late, but I'm writing to anyone who visits this topic for help.

If you have an enum, and you'd like to return a specific parameter of its values by default without calling a get function, you need to insert an @Override above your selected function, like:

```
public class Plants {
  public enum Fruits {
    APPLE ("sweet"),
    GRAPEFRUIT ("sour");

    private String taste;

    Fruits (String taste) {
      this.taste = taste;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTaste() {
      return this.taste;
    }
  }
}
```

And now you can call whichever enum value you'd like, without a get function:

```
Plants.Fruits.APPLE
```

And it'll return "sweet"

P.S. I'm not a professional programmer, please correct me if I've written something anti-conventional by accident.